# Is there a way to get the type of an exception in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Let's make the following assumptions:

- my program aborts due to an uncaught exception
- I have no idea what the type of that exception is
- the printed error message contains no hint on the exception type

How would I find out the type of that exception?

Minimal example:

```
main = error "foo"
```

(Here it's of course `ErrorCall`, but you can't tell from the error message.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes.  All `Exception` types must be instances of `Typeable`, assuming you use the new exceptions API.

```
import Control.Exception
import Data.Typeable
import Prelude hiding (catch)

realMain = error "example"
main = realMain `catch` h where
  h (SomeException e) = do
    putStrLn $ "Caught exception of type " ++ show (typeOf e)
    putStrLn $ show e
```

Results:

```
Caught exception of type GHC.Exception.ErrorCall
example
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  I have not, but I assume that this will print `SomeException`.

Comment: The Haskell code `(SomeException e)` does **not** mean that `e` has type `SomeException`, that would be written `e :: SomeException` (but that can't appear in patterns).  The only appearance of `SomeException` above is as a constructor.  So there are two things called `SomeException`: the type and the constructor.

Comment: Ah, haven't read your code properly.  So yes, that will indeed work.  Not at the first shot for exceptions that sit deep in the hierarchy, but I can get there step by step.

Comment: Also watch out with `SomeException` being both a type and a data constructor (like `data T = T a`): `\(SomeException e)` is different from catch `\(e :: SomeException)`. The first one unwraps, the second doesnt. If you call `typeOf e` on the second, it will always return `SomeException` instead of what you expect.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, thanks for the good answer. This will print "type constructor" name of an exception. Do you know if it's possible to print a "data constructor"? For example is it possible to get `"DivideByZero"` back instead of `"ArithException"`?

λ> show . typeOf $ DivideByZero
"ArithException"

Comment: @IlyaSilvestrov: That’s not possible with `Exception`, but if you are trying to test if something is a `DivideByZero` error you should just catch the `ArithException` and do a pattern match.